Multiple List Attachments in SharePoint 2019 List
I'm running SharePoint 2019, and I have InfoPath available to me.  I know it's terrible, but the migration is happening end of next year so it is what it is.
Onto my question.  I have a requirement that has Choice Column, Choose A, please provide the following 4 documents.  Choice B, please provide three required documents.  Now, they might not all need to provide those documents at the start, but we'd like a way to state what documents you need to provide for Choice B.  If it was O365, it would be much easier.
I know you can do something like this with InfoPath and repeating tables, but it's been a while since I've messed with InfoPath, I'm also open to an OOTB solution.  I'd appreciate any guidance.
